# <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/> Did not work

Tags: java, html, css

I have no idea why it does not work.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<p class="color">hallo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And

```
.color {
    color: blue;
}
```

I have tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/main.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/main.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/main.css"/>
```

And other way

When I put the CSS file in the folder with the file html and `href="main.css"` then it works very well.

In other projects I did not have such problems with the static folder.
I tried to restart IDE also.

Comment: My mistake, if we take a look at the front, we test it in the browser, it's actually how the guys write, you have to give these dots. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/main.css"/>  However, in Spring Boot there is a static folder that preserves its contents as if it were in a directory with html files. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inside the templates folder, so you have to go up on folder by using two dots and then go in the static folder.

So like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/main.css"/>
```

Comment: It works! thanks but like i say in other project, In another project I have the same organized catalogs and works with <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"> . I do not understand why it does not work now I would like to understand it.

Comment: Probably because the css folder is in the same directory as your html file. You always have to start from your current directory and go where needed from there

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot of how your files are organised, you may want to try an href of "../static/main.css", as this is a relative path name.

Comment: It works! thanks but like i say in other project, In another project I have the same organized catalogs and works with <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"> . I do not understand why it does not work now I would like to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Update header like this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/main.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

- / is the root of the current drive;
- ./ is the current directory;
- ../ is the parent of the current directory.

If you use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
```

the page are finding the file in the same folder of the html file